# Integral representation of the resolvent of a semigroup

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, laplace-transform, semigroups-of-operators

Let $T(t)$ be a $C_{0}$-semigroup with the generator $A$. Now, does the so called integral representation of the resolvent 
$$
(\lambda - A)^{-1} = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t\lambda}T(t) dt
$$
hold for all $\lambda$ whose real part is strictly greater than the spectral bound $S(A)$ of the generator? (It is clear this representation holds if $S(A)$ is replaced by the growth bound, $\omega_{0}$, of the semigroup.)

This result holds for positive semigroups but how about in general?

Answer (score 3):

No, this cannot hold in general. An argument is the following.

If a Laplace transform representation of the resolvent holds for all $\Re\lambda>\omega$, then $\omega\geq \omega_1(A)$, see

Arendt, Batty, Hieber, Neubrander, [Vector-valued Laplace Transforms and Cauchy Problems](http://rd.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-0348-0087-7), Proposition 5.1.5. (and the definitions in Section 5.1).

Example 5.1.10 in the same book provides an example of a semigroup (in a Hilbert space) such that
$$s(A)<\omega_1(A)$$
showing that the Laplace transform representation formula cannot be true for all $\Re\lambda>s(A)$.